# How do I keep a form in focus when a new one is added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, blur

Here's a fiddle:  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u7RfL/)

```
function blanker(){ 
    var c = $('.whatever').html().replace("thisWillBlank", "<form><input type='text' 
            id='thisWillBlank'></form>");
    $('.whatever').html(c); 
}

$('#alreadyBlanked').focus(); 

setTimeout(function(){blanker()}, 3000);
```

Using JS/jquery/css I would just like for whichever form that has been clicked on, to remain in focus even if new ones appear.  Thanks.

Comment: don't replace it while it's focused...seems simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the elements, so the old element is no longer available, but as long as it has an ID, you can target that instead:

```
function blanker(){ 
    var active = document.activeElement.id;
    var c = $('.whatever').html().replace("thisWillBlank", "<form><input type='text' id='thisWillBlank'></form>");
    $('.whatever').html(c); 
    $('#'+active).focus();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u7RfL/2/)

Comment: The text seems to disappear if I'm typing when the new blank appears.  How can I have it so that if I'm typing the text isn't erased mid-word?   THanks a lot. ^_^

Comment: Close, but I basically just want to be able to continue typing in to the textbox like as if nothing has been added, while forms are in fact being added.  The way it is now saves what I've typed, but jumps me to a different box.  I tried http://jsfiddle.net/u7RfL/4/ but still no luck.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You're replacing the elements, so you can't expect it to act as nothing happened when something did in fact happen. The only way to keep the value is to save it and reapply it, as the old element is removed. Other than that, you have to figure out a way to do it without removing the element.

Comment: `$('p '+word)` is not a valid selector, the text isn't an element, it's just a textnode, so it's not selectable like that.