# replace() works fine for text-node, but replaceWith() method does not? Why?

Tags: jquery, replace, replacewith

I'm trying to replace a text-node using the `replaceWith()` method.  I can find a string within an element using the `replace()` method, and replace it with anything I want, but the same doesn't seem to be true of replaceWith().

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LeQgN/1/)

Why is this, and is there a way do it?

```
var word = 'NOT work';

var sent = $('#without').html().replace(word, 'WORK'); 
$('#without').html(sent);

$("#with "+word).replaceWith('work');
```

Comment: replaceWith, and any jQuery method really, works on DOM elements, not textnodes.

Comment: Hi adeneo ;) Is there an ideal way for finding strings and replacing them?  Because right now i'm leaning towards using replace(word, "<div id="something">word</>), and than using replaceWith().  Seems kind of round about.  Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.replaceWith()` replaces an entire DOM element.  What you are trying to do is to change the some of the text of a single text node which is part of an element.  There is no single function in the DOM or in jQuery that changes just part of a text node or part of the text of an element.  The only way you do that is to fetch the text, make the changes you want to it and set it back.

You could create your own jQuery method that would do that.

```
$.fn.replaceText = function(srcText, replacementText) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var item = $(this);
        var txt = item.text();
        item.text(txt.replace(srcText, replacementText));
    });
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/U8k8C/

Comment: @Squirrl - what exactly is your problem then as I thought this does what your question asks.

Comment: I want to keep a form in focus and type in it normally while other new forms appear.  It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182545/how-do-i-keep-a-form-in-focus-when-a-new-one-is-added , but I gave the checkmark away even though it only partially solved my problem.  Maybe I should be a little stingier with the correct answers, but I always appreciate anything that pushes me in the right direction.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Squirrl - this answers everything you ask for in your question.  If you have further requirements, we would need to know what those are.  If you want to change text without disturbing other nearby HTML or event handlers, then you have to be very fine grained about what exactly you change because changing an element's `.innerHTML` or the text version of that recreates all the child elements.  It is possible to change only the text in a text node without disturbing any other parts of the HTML, but that is a different question and different answer.

Comment: @Squirrl - ...previous comment continued.  If you want help with that other question, feel free to post a new question that specifies more of the requirements.   Post a link as a comment here and that will bring it to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.replaceWith()` which replaces DOM elements, use `.text('mystring')` or `.html('my string that may have <abbr>HTML</abbr> in it')`

EDIT - I think I misunderstood what you're trying to do. It seems like you're just trying to wrap a piece of text with HTML. Your best bet is to use the `.replace()` function as you mentioned in your comments.

Comment: Wouldn't that replace all the html with 'mystring'?  I would like to just replace one text-node, within the html with 'mystring'